# apply mousewheel feature for this horizontal list?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, mousewheel

Hello good people of stack overflow. Please I need assistance on how to apply a mousewheel feature to this horizontal list I made.

When I hover my mouse on the portion I expect other items (whose overflow is hidden) to show up - you know, just like a normal mousewheel scrolling - but this time, for a horizontal list like this...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>mousewheel question</title>
    <style>
        div#main_container{
            width: 100vw;
            font-family: 'Maven Pro';
            /*background-color: #8a5bcb;*/
        }
        #categories{
            width: 100%;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
        }

        #inner_categories{
            width: 1200px;
            display: flex;
            /*flex-wrap: wrap;*/
            white-space: nowrap;
            overflow-y: hidden;
        }

        #inner_categories::-webkit-scrollbar{
            height: 6px;
        }
        #inner_categories::-webkit-scrollbar-track{
            background-color: transparent;
        }
        #inner_categories::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
            background-color: #efefef;
            border-radius: 10px;
        }
        #inner_categories::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover{
            background-color: #df00df;
        }

        .category{
            font-size: 12px;
            text-transform: capitalize;
            background-color: #ef00ef;
            padding: 2.5px 5px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            margin: 7px 0 9px 0;
        }

        .category:not(:last-child){
            margin-right: 6px;
        }

        .category:hover{
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="categories">
        <div id="inner_categories">
            <!-- ========== begin ========== CATEGORY TABS ========== begin ========== -->
            <div class="category">
                <span>grocery item</span>
            </div>
            <div class="category">
                <span>grocery item</span>
            </div>
            <div class="category">
                <span>grocery item</span>
            </div>
            <div class="category">
                <span>grocery item</span>
            </div>
            <div class="category">
                <span>grocery item</span>
            </div>
            <div class="category">
                <span>grocery item</span>
            </div>
            <div class="category">
                <span>grocery item</span>
            </div>
            <div class="category">
                <span>grocery item</span>
            </div>
            <div class="category">
                <span>grocery item</span>
            </div>
            <div class="category">
                <span>grocery item</span>
            </div>
            <div class="category">
                <span>grocery item</span>
            </div>
            <div class="category">
                <span>grocery item</span>
            </div>
            <div class="category">
                <span>grocery item</span>
            </div>
            <div class="category">
                <span>grocery item</span>
            </div>
            <div class="category">
                <span>grocery item</span>
            </div>
            <div class="category">
                <span>grocery item</span>
            </div>
            <div class="category">
                <span>grocery item</span>
            </div>
            <div class="category">
                <span>grocery item</span>
            </div>
            <div class="category">
                <span>grocery item</span>
            </div>
            <div class="category">
                <span>grocery item</span>
            </div>
            <div class="category">
                <span>grocery item</span>
            </div>
            <!-- ========== end ========== CATEGORY TABS ========== end ========== -->
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to the bottom of your `</body>`. In this case is `inner_categories` the container.

```html
    <script>
        var item = document.getElementById("inner_categories");
        window.addEventListener("wheel", function (e) {
            if (e.deltaY > 0) item.scrollLeft += 100;
            else item.scrollLeft -= 100;
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: you just helped me with a nagging problem, thank you sir.